# event.preventDefault on key events doesn't work in Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, addeventlistener, keydown

I am trying to use preventDefault on a 'keydown' event. It works perfectly across all browsers except for Chrome on Android. Is there an alternative that should be used?

```js
var t = document.getElementById('test');

t.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input id="test" />
```

Edit: this appears to broken as of Android 8.1.0